# Correct way to check an XML file from PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

In a PowerShell v2 script, what is the correct way to read an XMl file?

I'm trying to use an XML file as config source so I can gracefully stop the parent PowerShell script.

Logic:
PowerShell script loops through an array.
At the end of each loop, the script checks an XML file to see if a flag has been set to stop.

```
$pathForceStop = "c:\theconfig.xml"

foreach($bean in $burrito)
{
  write-host $bean

  [xml]$xForceStop = Get-Content $pathForceStop
  if ($xForceStop.powerstop -eq "stop")
  {
     #stop running
     exit
  }
}
```

Is this the correct and or most efficient way to read an XML file and avoid locking it?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, get-content reads a file line by line, which during that time would have locked the file.

This blog (http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2011/06/23/dealing-with-file-locks.aspx) mentions another way to read file content that's a bit faster and should decrease the amount of time the file is locked.

```
$file = [System.io.File]::Open("$env:windir\windowsupdate.log", 'Open', 'Read', 'ReadWrite')
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($file)
$text = $reader.ReadToEnd()
$reader.Close()
$file.Close()
```